# boost::Program_options A way to tell if the value from command line or ini file?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I would like to know if there is a way in Boost::Program_options that indicates where the value of an option ("abc" in my example) comes from whether it is from command line or an ini file.  The reason is that if the value is from an ini file, I would modify it.  Here is my option description:

```
po::options_description desc{ "Options" };
desc.add_options()
    ("abc", po::wvalue<std::wstring>()->required(), "Path to abc.txt")
    ("ini", po::wvalue<std::wstring>(), "INI file path.");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);

if (vm.count("ini"))  
{
    wifstream ifs(vm["ini"].as<std::wstring>(););
    if (ifs)
    {
        store(po::parse_config_file(ifs, desc, true), vm);
    }
}
```

As you can see, "abc" is a required option, so it can be entered from command line, ini file or from both method (with command line value has a higher priority).  As mention above, I would like to know if there is a way that indicates where the value of "abc" comes from so that I can modify the value accordingly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an elegant way to detect the source of an effective option's value, after you've notified all parse results and merged them into a single variables map.

However, you can get the desired results by parsing the command line tentatively at first, and storing both the inifile and the command line options before notify.

> This also removes the problem that the `notify()` before parsing the inifile would complain about missing mandatory option `--abc` if none was supplied at the command line.

A slight trick is to use `allow_unregistered()` to ignore all other options inside `boostrap_command_line()`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75f0aa82d3b848be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::variables_map boostrap_command_line(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description desc{ "Bootstrap Options" };
    desc.add_options()
        ("ini", po::value<std::string>()->default_value(""), "INI file path.");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).allow_unregistered().run(), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    return vm;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    po::options_description desc{ "Options" };

    auto boostrap = boostrap_command_line(argc, argv);

    desc.add_options()
        ("abc", po::wvalue<std::wstring>()->required(), "Path to abc.txt")
        ("ini", po::wvalue<std::wstring>(), "INI file path.");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

    if (boostrap.count("ini")) {
        // Sidenote: the standard does not allow `std::wifstream` to construct from
        // `std::wstring`, see
        // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream
        std::wifstream ifs(boostrap["ini"].as<std::string>());
        if (ifs) {
            store(po::parse_config_file(ifs, desc, true), vm);
        }
    }

    po::notify(vm);

    std::wcout << "abc option: " << vm["abc"].as<std::wstring>() << "\n";
}
```

Tests:

> **$** `./a.out --abc direct`

```
abc option: direct
```

> **$** `touch test.ini`
>   **$** `./a.out --ini test.ini`

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::required_option> >'
  what():  the option '--abc' is required but missing
bash: line 9: 11369 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out --ini test.ini
```

> **$** `echo abc=fromini >> test.ini`
>   **$** `./a.out --ini test.ini`

```
abc option: fromini
```

> **$** `./a.out --ini test.ini --abc cli-overrides`

```
abc option: cli-overrides
```

Comment: Thanks Sehe.  From your example, I am still having issue on determining whether the data is from ini file or command line, if I am using a if-statement to check the value.  This is similar to my original code, I can get the value, but my program would not be able to tell where the value comes from (ini file vs. command line).  Or am I missing something?   Thanks!

Comment: If you read my answer carefully, that's exactly what I said. However, I've read your _requirements_ that you were wishing to fulfil (_""abc" is a required option, so it can be entered from command line, ini file or from both method (with command line value has a higher priority)"_) and this code does exactly that. Why bother with if-statements for each setting?

Comment: I need the if-statement to determine if the data is from ini file.  If it is, then I would make it an absolute path.

Comment: Oh. Aha. You didn't say (and that's... questionable UX. I think the user will not expect different behaviour for the same options. How will you "make it" an absolute path, if not from the working directory? I'd suggest doing the same when running from the command line then)

Comment: Incidentally the first sentence exactly states what requirements would make it possible for you to achieve the manual logic you describe: _"I don't know an elegant way to detect the source of an effective option's value, after you've notified all parse results and merged them into a single variables map."_ - So here's the take that I didn't think very elegant: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bafa3ae0f7237c4

Comment: Thanks Sehe!  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Frank Did you notice that last comment answers your remaining questions? Please remember to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - Welcome to SO :)